# Data from ipcRender.once is undefined with Vue3 call

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, quasar-framework

in my preload I have this

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  func: (//redact) => {    
    const input = {
      //redact
    };
    let data;
    ipcRenderer.once(
      'response-' + input.responseId,
      function (event, reply) {
        data = JSON.parse(reply);
      }
    );
    ipcRenderer.send('request', input);
    return data //undefined but if I put return 'hello' I get hello back
  },
});
```

In the request the response is being sent with

```
electron.ipcMain.on('request', function (event, input) {
  //after data is fetched this is called
  event.sender.send(
    'response-' + responseId,
    reply
  );
...
```

this is being called in vue with:

```
window.electron.func(//redact)
```

I can log the data inside the .once callback - it's there
I just can't find a way to send it back.
I've tried returning from the .once,
I've tried making it async and using await on the vue call,
and lots of other ideas...
When I put a timeout where I have `return data` and console log data I can see it,
I just have to wait a second to for the data to be fetched from the db and returned
however if I put the return in the timeout its still just sending back undefined.
Is there a way to do this?
I've changed function names so I'm not just using 'func'

Thanks
This is a quasar project btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a promise to the preload function

```
func: (//redact) => { 
return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {   
    const input = {
      //redact
    };
    let data;
    ipcRenderer.once(
      'response-' + input.responseId,
      function (event, reply) {
        data = JSON.parse(reply);
        resolve(data)
      }
    );
    ipcRenderer.send('request', input);
    )}
  }
```

Then add a .then to the call

```
window.electron.func(//redact).then((reply)=>{processData(reply)}
//have to process all of the data in the .then using a helper function
```