# Is there a better way to lazy load a q-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm following https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#lazy-loading
I have

```
@filter="filterFn"
@filter-abort="abortFilterFn"
```

inside the q-select and filterFn is

```
     filterFn (val, update, abort) {
        if (options.value !== null) {
          // already loaded
          update()
          return
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
          update(() => {
            options.value = store.vehicles;
          })
        }, 2000)
      },
```

So when my api gets data back it puts it in my pinia store,
which is happening on selecting options from another q-select in a neighboring component.
I am watching that q-select's model and when it changes, I call my api
passing it parameters (that I now know because of the selection)
and updating the store once I have data.
However I have to wait for that data to come back that's why I'm using the lazy load.
It works, however a setTimeout is not efficient.
Sometimes that data is coming back really fast and sometimes there is a load time of a few seconds if there's a lot of options. And sometimes I don't know how long it will take. So if it's longer than 2 seconds that function wont load it into my q-select. it just shows blank. Yet I don't want to set it higher and have users wait 3 seconds for a call that may only take one second. I'm using a promise and resolve to get the data, how can I lazy load asynchronously?

so in my api I set the data for the q-select as follows:

```
case 'getVehicles':
  store.setVehicles(data.result); //switch on caller thats passed in
  break;
```

in a process data function that is called on the resolve as such:

```
    function retrieveData(input, params, caller) {
      window.electron
        .sendRequest(input, params)
        .then((reply) => {
          processData(reply, caller);
        });
    }
```

then my store I just set as such

```
    setVehicles(data: []) {
      this.vehicles = data;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the timeout function. It is meant in the example just to simulate a delayed response from an api, but not necessary in real life. You would likely want to return your store data as a computed prop, to properly watch the response from the api if relying on a Pinia store.

Comment: okay thanks let me try that

Comment: that seems to work only when my list of options is small. It doesn't actually set a loading circle when the list is long and its just blank

Comment: if I remove the if it updates but its wonky because there's no loading so it's just blank for awhile. If I select one option in the parent q-select (that has less options for this one) it pops up, great. But when I select the one that has more options it shows me the old options until I click it closed then open again a few times - it's not erasing the old values until it gets the new ones.

Comment: That could have more to do with the manner in which your Pinia state is updated from your api calls. We would need to see some additional code to try and troubleshoot that. Also, updating the entire state based on a single selection may not be the best use for Pinia. That may be better suited as a local state variable and store only the data you are saving with Pinia.

Comment: yeah that's how I'm going it I'm just setting whatever data I get back. I don't update the entire store. In this case it's just updating what going into options. I can try to share more code but I will have to redact some things

Comment: okay I added code on how the api is called and pinia is set
please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723372/data-from-ipcrender-once-is-undefined-with-vue3-call/74735386#74735386
that is how the retrieveData function is set up in the preload which calls the function I need to get data from

Comment: sendRequest not retrieveData sorry